# Haskell shift list

Tags: haskell, recursion

I want to shift a list by n elements to the left. Why do I get an error if I want to change the order from `(x:xs)` to `(xs:x)`?

```
shift n list@(x:xs)
    | n == 0 = list
    | otherwise = shift (n-1) (xs:x) -- (xs:x) error
```

> Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ [a]

I don't know how to interpret this error. Maybe someone of you can help me.
Thank you very much.

> **EDIT: As it was already mentioned, the correct term to use is rotate and not shift**

Comment: `(x:xs)` means you construct a list with `x` an element (type `a`), and `xs` the rest of the list (type `[a]`), but now you call it in a different way, hence the error.

Comment: It looks however that you want to *rotate* the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why do I get an error if I want to change the order from `(x:xs)` to `(xs:x)`?

Because the types do not match. The type of `(:)` is `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]`. It thus expects an element `x` (type `a`) and a list with the rest of the elements (type `[a]`). You can not just use `(:)` in the opposite way.

You can use the [**`(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-43--43-) to concatenate two lists together. We can thus rotate to the left by dropping `n` elements from the list and concatenating this with the first `n` elements of the list to this.

```
rotateL :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
rotateL 0 list = list
rotateL n list | n < 0 = error "Negative index"
               | otherwise = drop n list ++ take n list
```

or we can, like [@YannVernier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56108679/haskell-shift-list/56108803?noredirect=1#comment98851525_56108803) says, use [**`splitAt :: Int -> [a] -> ([a], [a])`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:splitAt):

```
rotateL :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
rotateL 0 list = list
rotateL n list | n < 0 = error "Negative index"
               | otherwise = lb ++ la
    where (la, lb) = splitAt n list
```

or without mentioning the `list` parameter:

```
rotateL :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
rotateL 0 = id
rotateL n | n < 0 = error "Negative index"
          | otherwise= uncurry (flip (++)) . splitAt n
```

> **Note**: based on how your attempt, I think you actually want to *rotate* the list to the left, not shift it, since that would mean that you simply `drop` the first `n` elements, and fill it perhaps with some extra value.

> **Note**: in case `n` is larger than the length of the list, then the `rotateL` will act as an identity function. That might not be the desired behavior. I leave it as an exercise to fix this edge-case.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the names that define the types, but the positions in a function call, or type declarations. If we check the type of `:`, we see that the second argument is a list:

```
Prelude> :t (:)
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

So pattern matching on this constructor will always give you the `head` and `tail`, not the `init` and `last`. Thus, using both `x:xs` and `xs:x`, you've declared that `a` and `[a]` are the same type, and the compiler balks. You could perform the append using e.g. `xs ++ [x]`.

[Data.Sequence](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.0.1/docs/Data-Sequence.html) has a type that does support both head and last patterns in the operators `:<|` and `|>:`.

In general, ([singly linked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Singly_linked_list)) lists only make the head element efficiently accessible; operations like appending or even checking lengths are costly. When all you need is a stream or stack, they're great, but a long distance reordering operation like the rotation is better handled by a [rope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(data_structure)) or [circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) type. Either is available in Haskell, in e.g. [container's Seq](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.0.1/docs/Data-Sequence.html) or [ring-buffer's RingBuffer](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ring-buffer-0.4/docs/Data-RingBuffer.html). [Data.ByteString.Lazy](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.2/docs/Data-ByteString-Lazy.html) and [Data.Text.Lazy](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.3.1/docs/Data-Text-Lazy.html) are also rope types.

Comment: Perhaps it is useful to note in your answer that `xs ++ [x]` is not the most efficient way, since this will turn the algorithm into an *O(n^2)* algorithm :).